# Angular app using a JQuery based UI Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm building an app in Angular 1 and have seen that I'm not supposed to interact directly with the DOM, rather I'm supposed to build custom directives to handle that interaction. I'm a bit new to web development in general, so I'm not sure how I would translate the JQuery examples given on the documentation at all of the UI Framework websites I've been looking at. For example, MaterializeCSS uses JQuery to [hide and show](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html) the side-nav.

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>

<script>$(".button-collapse").sideNav();</script>
```

Another example (what I'm currently stuck on) is their [modal dialog.](http://materializecss.com/modals.html#initialization)

```
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet">
<div class="modal-content">
  <h4>Modal Header</h4>
  <p>A bunch of text</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```

I have tried to see what's involved with calling the `.modal()` function from wihtin my controller, but it looks like it's a function that is returned from the JQuery selector. For functions that chain off the JQuery selector, is there no other way to invoke them, other than writing a directive and using JQuery in the directive? Or can I replace the JQuery usage with the `element.bind` and `element.$apply` stuff, invoking the UI Framework functions with the built in Angular `element` object? If not, do I have to worry about any life-cycle management since I'm interacting with the DOM through JQuery? I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) a couple [of posts](http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html), but none seem to answer my question because they don't address 3rd party functions chained off JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Angular users are quite blessed with a big community, you can pretty much find a ready made Angular wrapper for every popular Jquery plugins.

By typing `MaterializeCSS Angular` in Google I found this plugin [angular-materialize](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/), it should be easier to integrate into your Angular app than the Jquery version.

If you are interested, you can read into his source code to learn how to wrap particular component into Angular directive, such as [sidenav](https://github.com/krescruz/angular-materialize/blob/master/src/angular-materialize.js#L293)